# Converting HQL Query to Criteria generates invalid SQL

Tags: nhibernate

I am attempting to convert the following HQL query to Criteria.

```
from SubportfolioAudit as a
where a.ID in (select max(a2.ID)
                from SubportfolioAudit as a2
                where a2.EffectiveDate = :EffectiveDate
                    and a.Subportfolio.ID = a2.Subportfolio.ID
                group by a2.Subportfolio.ID)
and a.Subportfolio.ID in (:SubportfolioList)
```

So far I have the following:

```
var crit =  Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(SubportfolioAudit));
var currentAuditByEffectiveDate = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(SubportfolioAudit))
                                  .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                                                    .Add(Projections.Max("ID"))
                                                    .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Subportfolio.ID")))
                                  .Add(Expression.Eq("EffectiveDate", effectiveDate));

crit.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("ID", currentAuditByEffectiveDate));
crit.Add(Expression.In("Subportfolio.ID", subportfolioList.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray()));

return crit.List<SubportfolioAudit>();
```

Which generates an invalid sub query, you can see it here:

```
SELECT this_.SubportfolioAuditId        as Subportf1_21_6_,
       this_.Event                      as Event21_6_,
       this_.CreatedDate                as CreatedD3_21_6_,
       this_.[User]                     as User4_21_6_,
       this_.EffectiveDate              as Effectiv5_21_6_,
       this_.SubportfolioId             as Subportf6_21_6_,
       subportfol2_.SubportfolioId      as Subportf1_12_0_,
       subportfol2_.PACERCode           as PACERCode12_0_,
       subportfol2_.HedgeRatio          as HedgeRatio12_0_,
       subportfol2_.Name                as Name12_0_,
       subportfol2_.Strategy            as Strategy12_0_,
       subportfol2_.BasketId            as BasketId12_0_,
       subportfol2_.PortfolioId         as Portfoli7_12_0_,
       subportfol2_.ReferenceBasketId   as Referenc8_12_0_,
       (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN Count(* ) > 0
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END
        FROM   Asset
        WHERE  Asset.SubportfolioId = subportfol2_.SubportfolioId) as formula1_0_,
       basket3_.BasketId                as BasketId7_1_,
       basket3_.Name                    as Name7_1_,
       basket3_.CatsBenchmarkCode       as CatsBenc4_7_1_,
       basket3_.Description             as Descript5_7_1_,
       basket3_.BaseBasketId            as BaseBask6_7_1_,
       basket3_.Filename                as Filename7_1_,
       basket3_.Type                    as Type7_1_,
       basket4_.BasketId                as BasketId7_2_,
       basket4_.Name                    as Name7_2_,
       basket4_.CatsBenchmarkCode       as CatsBenc4_7_2_,
       basket4_.Description             as Descript5_7_2_,
       basket4_.BaseBasketId            as BaseBask6_7_2_,
       basket4_.Filename                as Filename7_2_,
       basket4_.Type                    as Type7_2_,
       portfolio5_.PortfolioId          as Portfoli1_5_3_,
       portfolio5_.BaseCurrencyCode     as BaseCurr2_5_3_,
       portfolio5_.TradingAccountNumber as TradingA3_5_3_,
       portfolio5_.Name                 as Name5_3_,
       portfolio5_.ClientId             as ClientId5_3_,
       client6_.ClientId                as ClientId4_4_,
       client6_.ExplicitFee             as Explicit2_4_4_,
       client6_.Affiliated              as Affiliated4_4_,
       client6_.ClientGroup             as ClientGr4_4_4_,
       client6_.RCODA                   as RCODA4_4_,
       client6_.Name                    as Name4_4_,
       client6_.BaseCurrencyCode        as BaseCurr7_4_4_,
       client6_.Region                  as Region4_4_,
       basket7_.BasketId                as BasketId7_5_,
       basket7_.Name                    as Name7_5_,
       basket7_.CatsBenchmarkCode       as CatsBenc4_7_5_,
       basket7_.Description             as Descript5_7_5_,
       basket7_.BaseBasketId            as BaseBask6_7_5_,
       basket7_.Filename                as Filename7_5_,
       basket7_.Type                    as Type7_5_
FROM   dbo.SubportfolioAudit this_
       inner join dbo.Subportfolio subportfol2_
         on this_.SubportfolioId = subportfol2_.SubportfolioId
       left outer join dbo.Basket basket3_
         on subportfol2_.BasketId = basket3_.BasketId
       left outer join dbo.Basket basket4_
         on basket3_.BaseBasketId = basket4_.BasketId
       left outer join dbo.Portfolio portfolio5_
         on subportfol2_.PortfolioId = portfolio5_.PortfolioId
       left outer join dbo.Client client6_
         on portfolio5_.ClientId = client6_.ClientId
       left outer join dbo.Basket basket7_
         on subportfol2_.ReferenceBasketId = basket7_.BasketId
WHERE  this_.SubportfolioAuditId in (SELECT   max(this_0_.SubportfolioAuditId) as y0_,
                                              this_0_.SubportfolioId           as y1_
                                     FROM     dbo.SubportfolioAudit this_0_
                                     WHERE    this_0_.EffectiveDate = '2009-09-11T00:00:00.00' /* @p0 */
                                     GROUP BY this_0_.SubportfolioId)
       and this_.SubportfolioId in (13 /* @p1 */,14 /* @p2 */,15 /* @p3 */,16 /* @p4 */,
                                    17 /* @p5 */,18 /* @p6 */,19 /* @p7 */,20 /* @p8 */,
                                    21 /* @p9 */)
```

I know that the Projections.GroupProperty() is causing the problem, but I cannot seem to find another way to accomplish what I want.

Comment: but why are you setting Projections.Max("ID")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe (and correct me if I am wrong) that the sub query is invalid because you are missing the second where clause you have set in your HQL (... and a.Subportfolio.ID = a2.Subportfolio.ID).

Converting your Criteria query as below I believe (cannot verify as I cannot test your code) that it will do the trick.

```
var crit = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(SubportfolioAudit), "mainQuery");
var currentAuditByEffectiveDate = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(SubportfolioAudit),"subQuery")
              .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                                .Add(Projections.Max("ID"))
                                .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Subportfolio.ID")))
              .Add(Expression.Eq("EffectiveDate", effectiveDate));
              .Add(Expression.EqProperty("subQuery.ID", "mainQuery.ID"));

crit.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("mainQuery.ID", currentAuditByEffectiveDate));
crit.Add(Expression.In("mainQuery.Subportfolio.ID", subportfolioList.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray()));

return crit.List<SubportfolioAudit>();
```

What I have done is to add an extra where clause in the DetachedCriteria that 'connects' the SubportfoliAudit.ID column of the subquery with the outer main query. I have also provided aliases to name the queries.

Comment: yeah your code produces the same problem. Basically the subquery returns two columns that are used in an IN statement which is invalid.

Comment: got it had to drop the group property completely it was not needed anyway. Thanks!

Comment: You are right. I believe your initial criteria code had an issue that my solution addressed but it was different than the one you asked help for. Sorry for that... It is true though that NHibernate will add the GroupBy column in the select statement when used through the ICriteria/DetachedCriteria interface. I believe there is no way around that. I hope I am wrong.